# Using all overloads of the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, using-statement, overriding

When a subclass overrides a baseclass's method, all of the baseclass's overloads are not available from the subclass. In order to use them there should be added a `using BaseClass::Method;` line in the subclass.

Is there a quick way to inheirt the baseclass's overloads for ALL of the overridden methods? (not needing to explicitly specify `using ...` for each method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's only possible with a `using` declaration and that only works with the individual methods.

Comment: I want to emphasize `using declaration`.  This is the keyword to search for more details, as `using` is used in several different contexts in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can access base class's method, by explicitly specifying scope of the class when you want to call method...

e.g

```
class Base{
 public: void foo(){}
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public: void foo(int){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    *d.Base::foo();* // like this
}
```